# How to Showing Icon With Same Folder to Another Page(Link)

Tags: javascript, php, html, codeigniter, bootstrap-4

i want to ask about showing the icon(picture). The icons just in path "img/icons" . But when i want showing in another page with link "xxx/xxx/xxx/xxx" has didnt showing the icon. The icon just showing with link "xxx/xxx". Because the icons is showing in navbar.php . But navbar.php is include in all link.

How to showing the icon with my code? Or you have a another code?

Please help meee

I'm using a framework Codeigniter with Bootstrap.

This is my code

```
<?php 
$current_url = current_url();
?>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">   
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a  class="nav-link <?=(site_url('/')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>"><img class="iconics" src=".\assets\img\icon\home-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('product')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('product') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\product-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link onclicks <?=(site_url('feed')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('feed') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\feed-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('confirm')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('confirm') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\payment-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('contact')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('contact') ?>"><img class="icons" src=".\assets\img\icon\contact-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: use absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As red suggested, use absolute path something like:

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="nav-content">   
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a  class="nav-link <?=(site_url('/')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>"><img class="iconics" src="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>assets\img\icon\home-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('product')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('product') ?>"><img class="icons" src="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>assets\img\icon\product-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link onclicks <?=(site_url('feed')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('feed') ?>"><img class="icons" src="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>assets\img\icon\feed-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('confirm')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('confirm') ?>"><img class="icons" src="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>assets\img\icon\payment-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link <?=(site_url('contact')==$current_url)?'clicks':''?>" href="<?php echo site_url('contact') ?>"><img class="icons" src="<?php echo site_url('/') ?>assets\img\icon\contact-icon.png" /></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The reason is with your code, it will try to find the icons relative to your current URL, which will not work on URLs other than your home page.

Answer (score 0):

```
 First set your base url in config.php then in your     controller
  retrieve the the base url.
  function index (){
      $data ['base'] = $this->config->item ('base_url');
      $this->load->view ('your_view',$data);
  }
 So if your bootstrap is located 
  http://example.com/css/icons.css
 In your view
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo        
    $base;?>css/icons.css">

 Include that in whatever view do you have. In that case you can acccess your icons in whatever path your view is located
```